# Mybatis: Return nested map from select without N+1 selects (i.e. not using @Many or result mapped sub-queries)

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

For a trivial query:

```
select primaryKey, secondaryKey, attributeOne, attributeTwo
```

And a trivial domain object:

```
public class ExampleDto {
    Integer primaryKey;
    Integer secondaryKey;
    String attributeOne;
    String attributeTwo;
}
```

I would like the following:

```
Map<PrimaryKey, Map<SecondaryKey, ExamplDto>>
```

My current approach is to have an extra Dto object:

```
<resultMap id="ExampleCollection" type="ExampleCollectionDto" autoMapping="true">
    <id property="primaryKey" column="primaryKey" javaType="integer"/>
    <collection property="values" ofType="ExampleDto" autoMapping="true">
        <id property="primaryKey" column="primaryKey" javaType="integer"/>
        <id property="secondaryKey" column="secondaryKey" javaType="integer"/>
    </collection>
</resultMap>

public class ExampleCollectionDto {
    Integer primaryKey;
    List<ExampleDto> values;

    public Map<Integer, KeyedValue> getMap() {
        Map<Integer, ExampleDto> results;
        for(ExampleDto value : values) {
            results.put(value.secondaryKey, value);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

And map it via

```
public interface ExampleMapper {
    @MapKey("primaryKey")
    Map<Integer, ExampleCollectionDto> getExampleCollectionDtoMap();
}
```

Is there any way (via annotation or xml mapping) to avoid having to have the collecting DTO, either using basic MyBatis functionality or by injecting myself in the result processing flow? I.e.

```
public interface ExampleMapper {
    // possibly some annotation here
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ExampleDto>> getExampleDtoMap();
}
```

So far the only way I've been able to figure out how to do this runs into the N+1 query problem (and I already have all the data I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want as method in mapper interface doesn't return value directly but still may be an option.

You can try to use custom `ResultHandler` to post process result:

ExampleMapper.xml

```
<resultMap id="ExampleDtoMap" type="ExampleDto" autoMapping="true">
    <id property="primaryKey" column="primaryKey" javaType="integer"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getExampleDtoMap" resultMap="ExampleDtoMap">
    select * from example_table
</select>
```

ExampleMapper.java

```
public interface ExampleMapper {
    void getExampleDtoMap(ResultHandler handler);
}
```

MyService.java

```
class MyResultHandler implements ResultHandler {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ExampleDto>> result = new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public void handleResult(ResultContext context) { 
        ExampleDto dto = (ExampleDto)context.getResultObject(); 
        Map<Integer, ExampleDto> map = result.get(dto.primaryKey);
        if (map == null) {
            map = new HashMap<>(); 
        }                  
        map.put(dto.secondaryKey, dto);
    }
};
MyResultHandler handler = new MyResultHandler();
ExampleMapper exampleMapper = ...;
exampleMapper.getExampleDtoMap(handler);

return handler.result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As you said, It's not exactly what I want, but I have a feeling that this is the best I'm going to get.  If there's no better response in 4 days I'll mark it correct and move on.